# PHP logging error of previous day in todays error log file

Tags: php, apache

I set my application to generate php error logs daily using

```
ini_set('error_log', $gConfig->fs_root . '/logs/php_error_'.date('Y_m_d').'.log');
```

But I noticed in one of the file there are logs from the next day (i.e `php_error_2021_02_09.log` contain error log of 2021-02-10).

What could be the cause?

Comment: Can you show us an example of code where logging is taking place?

Comment: Is it possible the server's system date to be not like current date ?

Comment: Is the PHP process long lived? It could be that `ini_set` was called while it was 2021-02-09 the PHP process did a bunch of time consuming processing and by the time the error was thrown it was the next day. Especially if it was started late at night